# Python BeautifulSoup can't identify div tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here I'm doing web-scraping with Python bs4. I want to filter out the `div` tag whose `class` attribute's value is `a-column a-span6 a-span-last`. This div tag indeed exists (as in the picture), but BeautifulSoup can't identify div tag. Wondering why?

Here is the screenshot.
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGvf1.png)

EDIT:
Code Attached:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import ssl
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url='https://www.amazon.com/Acer-SB220Q-Ultra-Thin-Frame-Monitor/dp/B07CVL2D2S/ref=zg_bs_electronics_35?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=YGK101A649HEC8NXXM1T'
req=urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'})
response=urllib.request.urlopen(url=req,context=ctx)
html=response.read().decode('utf-8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
soup.find_all('div','a-column a-span6 a-span-last',recursive=True)
```

Comment: Try this--Soup.find_all('div', {'class':'a-column a-span6 a-span-last'})

Comment: Might be an issue with the HTML. The issue is not replicable with just bs4

Comment: the page is likely dynamic and rendered through JS. BeautifulSoup can;t find what's not there, and that tag is likely not present in the source html.

Comment: @VikasSharma Just now I tried, but the result itself is still an empty list.

Comment: @chitown88 Thanks. The URL is 'https://www.amazon.com/Roku-Streaming-Player-Premium-Headphones/dp/B07WVF9SL5?_encoding=UTF8&amp'. I checked that the div tag is indeed included in the source HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ok. I see it.

The issue is with `html.parser`. Depending on the parser used, you could get back different results. Read more about it [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

But change to 'lxml' gave me an output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import ssl
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url='https://www.amazon.com/Acer-SB220Q-Ultra-Thin-Frame-Monitor/dp/B07CVL2D2S/ref=zg_bs_electronics_35?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=YGK101A649HEC8NXXM1T'
req=urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'})
response=urllib.request.urlopen(url=req,context=ctx)
html=response.read().decode('utf-8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')   # <----- CHANGE MADE HERE
soup.find_all('div',{'class':'a-column a-span6 a-span-last'})
```